# Maximmum and minimum values of function in interval

Tags: calculus

Hello I would like to learn the following from this site and members.

How to find the intervals ( Increasing and decreasing) of the function and its Maximum and minimum value, where the function: $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$.

Thanking you all.

Comment: Question is not clear to me...do you want the points where the function has a maximum and a minimum?

Comment: Don't dare, complete the square!

Comment: Anupam! I want points where it is minimum and maximum. Also I want to know the increasing and decreasing intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In quadratic functions,

$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
x & -\infty & & -\dfrac{b}{2a} & & +\infty \\ \hline
y \ (a>0) & +\infty & \searrow & \text{minimum} & \nearrow & +\infty \\ \hline
y \ (a<0) & -\infty & \nearrow & \text{maximum} & \searrow & -\infty
\end{array}
$